# Confused with Java Servlets and HTML

Tags: java, servlets

Part of my homework for tomorrow is to search and add entries using Java EE. If the search is not existing, an add item option will show as follow:

Supposedly, when the Stock ID is not existing, It will be transfered to the Add Item Text Field of StockID. But I have no idea how to do it. My code is as follows:

Servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Item item = (Item) request.getAttribute("invenItem");
        if (item != null) {
            out.println("<html><title>Inventory Item</title>");
            out.println("<body><h1>Inventory Item Details:</h1>");
            out.println("Stock ID  : " + item.getStockID() + "<br/>");
            out.println("Name      : " + item.getItemName() + "<br/>");
            out.println("Unit Price: " + item.getUnitPrice() + "<br/>");
            out.println("On Stock  : " + item.getOnStock() + "<br/>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } else {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/DataForm.html");
            rd.include(request, response);
            out.println("Sorry Item not found..");
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("AddEntry.html");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Add Entry</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <h2>Add Item:</h2>
      Stock ID: <input type ="text" name ="stockId" value="???"> <br> <--how to get it?
      Item Name: <input type ="text" name ="name"> <br>
      Unit Price: <input type ="text" name ="unitPrice"> <br>
      On Stock : <input type ="text" name ="stock"> <br><br>
      <input type ="submit" value ="Add Item">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're approaching this the wrong way. HTML belongs in JSP files, not in Servlet classes. Also, EL `${}` doesn't run in plain HTML files at all, but in JSP files only. Rename your `.html` files to `.jsp`. This way EL like `${param.id}` will then also work, even though you still have a XSS attack hole open.

#### See also:

- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

(please read them, they contains hello world examples which should turn on some lights in your head)

Comment: but we are not yet allowed to use JSP.. :(

Comment: @BalusC and we hadn't tackled JSP yet.

Comment: Then do the HTML entirely in the servlet like `out.print("<input value=\"" + id + "\">");` (and shoot your tutor into oblivion for this '90s way of web programming). As to XSS, use Apache Commons Lang StringEscapeUtils (or homegrow one).

Comment: @BalusC But we need to use this: rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("AddEntry.html");
            rd.include(request, response);

Comment: You **can not** use EL in HTML, only in JSP. If your tutor wanted you to redisplay it in plain vanilla HTML, then he is teaching things wrong.

Comment: @BalusC Honestly Iam so confused.

Comment: Talk with your tutor, ask him how he would redisplay the request parameter in plain HTML. In the meanwhile, click the "See also" links to learn how to do it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the expression language (i.e. `${param.id}`) in plain HTML files. It'll only be interpreted in JSPs (files with a `.jsp` extension).