# how to translate servlet to JSP?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

Can you help me translate a **Servlet** to **JSP**

here's the code:

```
package Inventory;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class DisplayData extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Item item = (Item) request.getAttribute("invenItem");

    if (item != null) {
        out.println("<html><title>Inventory Item</title>");
        out.println("<body><h1>Inventory Item Details:</h1>");
        out.println("Stock ID  : " + item.getStockID() + "<br/>");
        out.println("Name      : " + item.getItemName() + "<br/>");
        out.println("Unit Price: " + item.getUnitPrice() + "<br/>");
        out.println("On Stock  : " + item.getOnStock() + "<br/>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    } else {
        RequestDispatcher rd =
           request.getRequestDispatcher("/SearchPage.html");
        rd.include(request, response);
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/AddData.html");
        rd.include(request, response);
    }

}
```

}

I am trying to use the scriplets, but still want to know how to convert:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

to JSP.  I try to do this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Display Data</title>
</head>
<jsp:useBean id="inventory" class="Inventory.AddData" />
<jsp:directive.page import="java.io.*" />
<jsp:directive.page import="javax.servlet.*" />
<jsp:directive.page import="javax.servlet.http.*" />
<body>

    <%-- But I don't know how to convert this:
         public class DisplayData extends HttpServlet
         in JSP
    --%>

</body>
```

please Help... thanks in advance

Comment: Is this your classmate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156438/confused-with-java-servlets-and-html Code is almost exactly the same. This user has also explicitly mentioned that the tutor didn't allow to use JSP in the course. See also the comments of my answer on the linked question. I'd love to help, but this is all a bit too suspicious :)

Comment: @BalusC.. yep.. :) now we are asking to convert it to JSP

Comment: Hover the `jsp` tag and click *info* link on the popbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way would be to use JSTL instead of scriptlets (check out a [good primer here)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211.html). In a nutshell, you need to have JSTL JARs installed (either in your app server or in your specific webapp). Then, you can do the following:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<c:out value="${invenItem.stockID}"/>
```

The first line imports the JSTL "core" tag library, which gives you access to the basic tags. Then, the  tag is used to output data - it will escape special characters for you (for example, suppose stockID has the character "<"). Finally, the ${} is an EL expression, which in this case simply accesses the invenItem request attribute and extracts the stockID value (by calling getStockID()).

Clean, simple, no ugly Java scriptlets in your JSP view.

Answer (score 0):

The JSP page is already compiled into a servlet. No need to extend one manually.

Comment: hi... but where can i find it? or how should i see it?

Comment: You don't need to see it usually. It's created behind the scenes somewhere in the working directory of the Servlet container.